# Is it ok to throw C++ exceptions in global scope?

Tags: c++, exception

Let's say you have this:

```
class MYEXC { ... };

class GlobalClass { 
    GlobalClass() { 
        try {
            throw MYEXC(...); 
         } catch(MYEXC& a) { ... };
    };
};

GlobalClass GlobalInstance;
```

I have been doing this for a long time, but currently I'm solving a really difficult heap corruption error on macOS, so I'm trying to use libgmalloc but once I link against this, all `try`/`catch` scopes stop working (maybe only in global scope, maybe not, I didn't get far enough).

Comment: Yes, it is okay to throw C++ exceptions that way, in that context (i.e., before `main()` is invoked).  An uncaught exception will terminate the program.

Comment: While it is indeed OK, it is usually a good idea to initialize your global objects _after_ main has started so that you can catch and print a useful diagnostic before terminating.

Comment: @Dúthomhas -- there's nothing that prevents the code in the question from printing a useful diagnostic before terminating. It's all in the `...` in the `catch` clause.

Comment: Only SOIF if you aren’t careful.

Comment: Of the five semicolons in your code, the third and fourth are superfluous. In this case, they are no-ops, but you shouldn't get into the habit. If nothing else, it makes your code look bad to your co-workers.

Comment: @TonyK it's not really related to this and I'd beg to differ. Semicolon nicely notifies the reader that whatever is before, ends here. You can easily imagine examples, where this would be advantageous. You may certainly not agree, but that doesn't make such coding practice "bad".

Comment: Well, I was only trying to help. You can continue to look silly if you like. In fact, why stop at a single semicolon? After a particularly important function, you could type five semicolons to attract the reader's attention. It would still compile :-)

Comment: @TonyK you shouldn't really be "trying to help"...